# Adding to a ComboBox in Visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, ora-12154

I want the user of the program to be able to add a High School name to an already populated
ComboBox.  I added 4 different High Schools to the ComboBox at design time.  I have a MenuStrip with an Edit tool and Add High School tool.  Here is the code I have written:

```
Private Sub AddHighSchoolToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddHighSchoolToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add("")
End Sub
```

When I run the program, the 4 High School appear, when I "Add High School" I get a blank space.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are entering an empty string to the ComboBox.

Try this instead,

```
Dim schName As String

    schName = InputBox("Enter your High School name", "High School name")

    If Not schName = "" Then

        ComboBox1.Items.Add(schName)

    End If
```

Comment: Shadow Wizard! Thanks a lot, this worked.  I wanted the user to be able to add the High School directly into the dropdown ComboBox but this will work also.  I will play around with it and see what i come up with.  I really appreciate you helping, take care!

Comment: @otisjefferson What do you mean by _add the High School directly into the dropdown ComboBox_ ? .BTW I'm not the Shadow Wizard :)